# Print data from Tkinter Entry does not work

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I recently started coding and wanted to try something.

I wanted to print the data from an Entry widget (tkinter).
But somehow it does not work, can someone explain why and what didn't work.
I tried to troubleshoot but without success.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

userInput1 = tk.StringVar()
userInput2 = tk.StringVar()


def pri():
    first = userInput1.get()
    print(first)


canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=600, width=400, bg='grey',)
canvas.pack()

entry1 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=userInput1)
entry1.pack()

entry2 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=userInput2)
entry2.pack()

button = tk.Button(root, text='Create Directory', fg='white', bg='green', command=pri())
button.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

I'm really clueless, I watched some tutorials and did exactly what they did. :(

Comment: Change `command=pri()` to `command=pri`

Comment: Also there is no need to `userInput1`. You can just use `entry1.get()` instead of `userInput1.get()`